# how to get correct FileExtension for word document from ContentVersion received in mail attachment for pdf its correct but for its not .docx for word

Tags: singleemailmessage, contentversion, emailfileattachment

Hi I am getting wrong extension or type for word document from ContentVersion in mail attachment for pdf its coming correct but for its not .docx for word I debug its coming WORD_X which is wrong and I am unable to open my attachment below is my class

```
public class FrContractLegalApprovalMail {

    @InvocableMethod
    public static void sendContractEmail(List<id> contractIds){
      Id userId;
      string emailTo;
      Blob b;
      Messaging.SingleEmailMessage semail= new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    
      EmailTemplate emailTemp = [SELECT Id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName ='Fr_Contract_Approval_Mail' limit 1];
    
      Contract__c Contr = [select id,name,Contract_Attached__c,Contact__c,L_Person_Email__c,Customer_Account__c,Status__c,OwnerId,owner.email from Contract__c where id In :contractIds];
    

       if(Contr.Legal_Person_Email__c!=null && Contr.OwnerId!=null){
           userId=Contr.OwnerId;
           emailTo=Contr.L_Person_Email__c;
       }
      
       List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment> fileAttachments = new List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment>();   
      
        for(Id cId :contractIds){    
           for(ContentDocumentLink contentLink : [SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId = :cId limit 1]){
               for (ContentDocument contentDocument : [SELECT Id, LatestPublishedVersionId FROM ContentDocument WHERE Id = :contentLink.ContentDocumentId limit 1]){
                   for(ContentVersion document : [SELECT Id, Title, VersionData,FileType FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id = :contentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionId limit 1]){
  
                      system.debug('** Inside Contract Attachment: ' +document);

                      Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachment = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
                      b=document.VersionData;
                      attachment.setBody(b);
                      attachment.setFileName(document.Title + '.' + document.FileType);

                     fileAttachments.add(attachment);
                   }
               }
           }
           list<String> emailIds= new list<String>();
           emailIds.add(emailTo);
           system.debug('**Contract emailIds: ' +emailIds);
           semail.saveAsActivity = false;
           semail.setTemplateId(emailTemp.Id);
           semail.setTargetObjectId(userId);
           semail.setWhatId(cId);
           semail.setToAddresses(emailIds);
           //semail.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[]{fileAttachments});
           semail.setFileAttachments(fileAttachments);
       }
       Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{semail});
           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line you use the FileType to use as the files extension, while you want the FileExtension field.

```
attachment.setFileName(document.Title + '.' + document.FileType);
```

If your file is over 3 mb then the standard setting is to send is as an HMLT download link. If you don't want this then [this help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000320299&type=1&mode=1) will explain how to change that:

> In Salesforce Classic
>
> Click on Setup.
> In the Quick Find box, enter email attachment.
> Click on Email Attachments under Email Administration.
> Make a selection on the right side under 'Default Behavior for Email Attachments.'
> Click on Save.
>
> In Lightning Experience
>
> Click on the gear icon and click Setup.
> In the Quick Find box, enter email attachments.
> Click on Email Attachments under Email.
> Make a selection on the right side under 'Default Behavior for Email  Attachments.' ​
> Click on Save.

Comment: Hi Kasper thanks for your time and answer I tried FileExtension as well its still sending docx file as .html file

Comment: Hi @priyadhawan, that's odd. I don't see anything in your code that should cause that.  If you query the ContentDocuments, does it return the correct FileType? Does the file name contain a . in itself perhaps? Does the file open correctly if you change it to an docx extension?

Comment: Hi @Kasper I found that salesforce sends over 3 mb file as HTML link i didn't notice below 3 mb its working fine so Let me know if you know any solution to it otherwise I am good and Thanks for your help much appreciate your time

Comment: @priyadhawan Oh I forgot about that. Luckily you can change that. I've edited my answer to include that.